# rotating an object in OpenGL ES , android platform

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, thread-sleep

I have drawn a square in `openGL` ES on android platform , i just want to make the impression of it rotating for several times and i want to see the square while rotating.

```
for(float i=0;i<1000;i++){


gl.glRotatef(40f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Thread.sleep(100);   // put the thread to sleep for 1 sex

}
```

But its not working properly , in only make it rotate one .

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your drawing routine? If you just itereate a thousand times to apply rotation, but aren't actually drawing, you'll never see the rotation in effect.

Comment: draw your scene inside the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

you need to gl.flush() the buffer into the screen.

Also why are you using a float in a for ?

Comment: its for a thing later on the code, so i put gl.flush()  in the body of the loop ?